# Objetos anidados entre ellos en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Mi problema es que no estoy seguro de cómo hacer para listar los datos del objeto Personas. Además, trabajar con ellos.

```js
//Creamos el objeto
function Personas(nombre, ape, edad) {
  this.nombre = nombre;
  this.apellido = ape;
  this.edad = edad;

  this.viajero = {
    codigo: new Array(10),
    paises: new Array(10),
    puntos: false,
  };

  //Función que muestra todos los datos
  var mostrarViajeros = function () {
    return (
      this.nombre +
      " " +
      this.apellido +
      " " +
      this.edad +
      " " +
      this.viajero.codigo +
      " " +
      this.viajero.paises +
      " " +
      this.viajero.puntos
    );
  };
}

//Operaciones de gestión de usuarios
function Gestion(eleccion) {
  this.elegir = eleccion;

  //Métodos
  switch (eleccion) {
    case "crear":
      var id = prompt("Codigo del nuevo viajero");
      if (Personas.viajero.codigo.find((elemento) => elemento == id)) {
        document.write("Este viajero ya existe en la base de datos");
      } else {
        Personas.viajero.codigo.push(id);
      }
      break;

    //Desdoble de posibilidades
    case "eliminar":
      var elimino = prompt("¿País o viajero?");

      //Muestro opciones
      switch (elimino) {
        case "pais":
          var idViajero = prompt("Código del viajero");
          if (
            Personas.viajero.codigo.find((elemento) => elemento == idViajero)
          ) {
            var quitarPais = prompt("Eliminar el país: ");
            Personas.viajero.paises.splice(quitarPais, 1);
          } else {
            document.write("Este viajero no existe en la base de datos");
          }
          break;

        case "viajero":
          var eliminando = prompt(
            "Inserte el código del viajero para eliminar"
          );
          Personas.viajero.codigo.splice(eliminando, 1);
          break;
      }

      break;

    case "mostrar":
      Personas.mostrarViajeros();
      break;

    case "añadir":
      var añadiendo = prompt("Código del viajero");
      if (Personas.viajero.codigo.find((elemento) => elemento == añadiendo)) {
        var paisVacaciones = prompt("Añadir el país: ");
        Personas.viajero.paises.push(paisVacaciones);
      } else {
        document.write("Este viajero no existe en la base de datos");
      }
      break;
  }
}

//Pruebas
var nuevoViajero = new Personas("Victor", "Faustino", 15);

document.write(Personas.mostrarViajeros);
```

Mi problema reside en la anidación de viajeros dentro del objeto Personas, me gustaría que hubiese alguien que me guiase con esto si puede ser. Soy novato en JS y vengo de programar en Java así que todavía me cuesta comprender bien la sintaxis del lenguaje.

Pondré el enunciado del problema a modo de ayuda a la comunidad para aclarar un poco más lo que se pide.

```
<!--
            Vamos a crear una pequeña base de datos de viajeros para una agencia de viajes:

            Crea una estructura para guardar los datos de personas (nombre, apellidos, edad)
            
            A partir de la estructura anterior, vamos a añadir los datos de los viajeros: una lista de países visitados (los países NO se pueden repetir) y si 
            tiene o no tarjeta de puntos en nuestra agencia 
            
            Ahora crea otra estructura para guardar los datos de los viajeros, los identificaremos por un código de cliente de nuestra agencia
            
            Crea las siguientes funciones/métodos para gestionar nuestra base de datos:
                Crear un nuevo viajero (debe comprobar si el código de cliente ya existe. Si es así, muestra un mensaje y no lo inserta)
                Eliminar un viajero (identificado por su código de cliente)
                Mostrar todos los viajeros (sus datos personales, qué países ha visitado y si tiene tarjeta)
                Añadir un país a un viajero (identificado por su código de cliente)
                Eliminar un país a un viajero (identificado por su código de cliente)
                
            Haz algunas pruebas para comprobar que todo funciona bien, realizando llamadas a las funciones/métodos antes creados.
        -->
```

Esta es la pregunta del ejercicio.

Comment: Parece que todo trata de administración de viajeros. No debería haber un arreglo de viajeros que sirva como base de datos?

Comment: Precisamente el problema que se me plantea es de hacer un acercamiento a una base de datos para practicar con las funciones que se pueden ver como objetos. Debido a mi falta de experiencia con la sintaxis no conozco muy bien cómo sería para mostrar Personas con su respectivo viajeros y la función que alberga.

Comment: Ayudaría si agregaras el planteamiento del problema. Quienes son los viajeros, las personas, como se relacionan entre ellos.

Comment: Creo que posiblemente hayas invertido la lógica: un objeto Viajeros puede tener al interior Personas, No veo como dar sentido a un objeto persona con viajeros en su interior (aunque, tratándose de **constructos** dónde el nombre es un accidente pueda hacerse) sugiero dos alternativas 1. Conmuta los nombres. 2 Pon nombres dummie como clase1 y clase2 para que el **sentido común** no choque y no te haga trampas.

Comment: Un viajero es una persona con mas acciones o datos. Yo creo que el enfoque esta mal deberías crear una clase base `Persona` y en ella poner el comportamiento que puede ser compartido por cualquier persona. Y luego crear la clase `Viajero` que herede de `Persona` y ahí poner los datos y comportamiento único del viajero.

Comment: Gracias, voy a intentarlo. ¿Cómo puedo poner me gusta a las respuestas y demás?